# Estimation of t-distribution by mean of samples does not work

Tags: numpy, distribution

I am trying to create a t-distribution by taking the mean of many samples from a normal distribution (and then estimating the shape with kernel density estimation).

For some reason, I am getting pretty different results when I compare what I get with a proper t-distribution. I don't understand what is going wrong, so I think I am confused about something.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn    

inner_sample_size = 10
X = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)

results = [
    np.mean(np.random.normal(size=inner_sample_size))
    for _ in range(10000)
]
estimation = gaussian_kde(results)
plt.plot(X, estimation.evaluate(X))

t_samples = np.random.standard_t(inner_sample_size, 10000)
t_estimator = gaussian_kde(t_samples)
plt.plot(X, t_estimator.evaluate(X))

plt.ylabel("Probability density")
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot I get:

[image: Different plots!]

Where the orange line is numpy's own t-distribution, and the blue line is the one estimated by sampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that the mean of Standard Normals has T distribution is incorrect. In fact, the mean of Standard Normals has Normal Distribution, which explains the shape of your blue graph. To generate one random variable `T` from a T distribution with `k` degrees of freedom, you first generate `k+1` independent Standard Normals `Z_i, i=0,...,k`. You then compute

`T = Z_0 / sqrt( sum(Z_i^2, i=1 to k)/k )`.

The sum of squared Standard Normals `sum(Z_i^2, i=1 to k)` has Chi-Squared Distribution with `k` degrees of freedom, so if there is a pre-canned method to generate this, you should use it, since it's likely more efficient.

Comment: Ah yes, the mean of the samples has to be distributed normally because of the central limit theorem doesn't it. I got confused as I was writing the code. Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually need the CLT to guarantee this. The reason that the mean is normal is that the Normal Distribution is a [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), which means that the sum of two independent normals is again normal up to location and scaling. Hence, the sum of any number of normals is normal. CLT guarantees that if you add a sufficiently large number, say 30, of iid random variables with (almost) arbitrary distribution, its mean is normal.